# Git pull in GitHub as collaborator

Tags: github

I'm the admin in a GitHub repository and I've added a collaborator, this collaborator needs to pull the repository and the system asks the access token.

How can a collaborator download a GitHub repository and how I create an access token for them?

Comment: They will need to create the access token / ssh keys for their account using the steps found in [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github). After then they can download and contribute with `git pull <reop_ur?>`

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution, basically the collaborator needs to create an access token and then clone the repository, when prompted for Username, fill the username and when prompted for password you need to put the access token (not the password).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to provide them an access token.  Assuming your repository is private, the collaborator needs to authenticate to GitHub when pulling (and when pushing even if the repository is public).  The should do that by setting up their own account appropriately.

That can be by using their own personal access token as the password when prompted for the username and password over HTTPS, which they can create in the settings page, or they can create an SSH key and upload the public part to GitHub, and then use SSH to clone from or push to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

The collaborater can clone the repo to their terminal using their own personal access token.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).